# Checking if a list of words exisit in a string

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to check if a list of words (or any one of them) exists in a string. I tried some of the examples i found here, but i still can't get it to work correctly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ss3="How to make a book";
    $words = array ("book","paper","page","sheet");
    if (in_array($ss3, $words) )
{
    echo "found it"; 
}
```

Comment: in_array will only checks the complete string value in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `explode()` your `$ss3` string and then compare each item with your `$words` with loop

manual for `in_array` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

manual for `explode()` - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

```
$matches = array();
$items = explode(" ",$ss3);
foreach($items as $item){
  if(in_array($item, $words)){         
     $matches[] = $item; // Match found, storing in array
  }
} 

var_dump($matches); // To see all matches
```

Comment: Note: This answer is invalid in terms of output. We have to check whether any or all of the elements of `$words`  are in the string, and not the other way around. For example this answer will say `to` is not in words but the OP doesn't want to check for that. They need to check only for the words contained in `$words`, please consider updating accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Loop over your array, check for each element if it exists in the string

```
$ss3="How to make a book";
$words = array ("book","paper","page","sheet");
foreach($words as $w){
  if (stristr($ss3,$w)!==false)
   echo "found $w \n"; 
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/485431)**

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will check for existence of a word from a string. Also remember that you must **first convert the string to lowercase** and then explode it.

```
$ss3="How to make a book";
$ss3 = strtolower($ss3);
$ss3 = explode(" ", $ss3);
    $words = array ("book","paper","page","sheet");
    if (in_array($ss3, $words) )
{
    echo "found it"; 
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) along with [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) like as

```
$ss3="How to make a book";
$words = array ("book","paper","page","sheet");
$new_str_array = str_word_count($ss3,1);
$founded_words = array_intersect($words,$new_str_array);
if(count($founded_words) > 0){
    echo "Founded : ". implode(',',$founded_words);
}else{
    echo "Founded Nothing";
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/i766s)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions. It would look something like this:

```
$ss3 = "How to make a book";

 if (preg_match('/book/',$ss3))
     echo 'found!!';
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array will only check the complete string value in an array.
Now you can try this:

```
$string = 'How to make a book';
$words = array("book","paper","page","sheet");
foreach ($words as $val) {
    if (strpos($string, $val) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Match found"; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "Not found!";
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you for better answer

```
    <?php
    $str="Hello World Good";
    $word=array("Hello","Good");
    $strArray=explode(" ",$str);
   foreach($strArray as $val){
   if(in_array($val,$word)){
   echo $val."<br>";
   }
   }

 ?>
```